# localeCompare unable to match if the text includes single quote

Tags: javascript, string-comparison

I am currently working on a Photoshop Plugin which loops over all the text inside each textLayer.

I then try to match that text with data from a spreadsheet which contains the same texts. The full functionality is used to be able to easily loop over text layers and translate them into different markets as the spreadsheet contains data for multiple languages.

So what im firstly interested in, is to compare the english text on the text layers with the english text row in the spreadsheet, to be able to determine if I have any translations for that specific text.

I am using localCompare you match th two different texts.

Currently when I using the following condition to determine if the texts matches.

```
if (textLayer.localeCompare(translationText, 'en', { sensitivity: 'base' }) === 0) {
    console.log(textLayer + translationText[l][0] + ' %c !Matches! ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
}
```

In my console I get the following results:

```
The Gift EditThe Gift Edit  !Matches!
We got just the right styles for you.We got just the right styles for you.  !Matches!
```

Which is also what I would expect, but as soon as I have texts which contain single quotes, I dont get any match as in the example below:

```
Haven't bought this year's gifts yet? Do not worry. Haven't bought this year's gifts yet? Do not worry.
```

I tried playing around with the sensitivity of the localCompare but I am unable to figure what the right setup would be. Does anyone know how this can be achieved. Let me know if I need to clarify more.

!EDIT!
By request in the comments I have tried to make a more clear example and by doing so I think I figured out what the error is. And it seems to be that one of the texts includes a breakline and the other one does not. See this codepen as an example:

https://codepen.io/fennefoss/pen/BaMpeaO?editors=1111

If you remove the breakline in variable 'a' the texts are matched. How can I do a comapre of two texts which ignores breaklines?

Comment: Are you sure the quotes are the problem? What about possible whitespace or zero width characters? Are the characters the exact same ones, rather than ones that look the same?

Comment: Your example is not really an example; there's no code. Show the test code that demonstrates the problem. (It's not really clear even what exactly the two strings being compared are.)

Comment: OK I will try to give a more clear example of the two text strings. 1 min. I will make a codepen.

Comment: Don't add your example as a comment. Edit the original post.

Comment: @MikkelFennefoss and you don't need to make a Codepen; StackOverflow has (basically) a Codepen facility built in.

Comment: Well there's a line break in one, and not in the other. What made you think the problem had to do with quote characters?

Comment: There's no option for `.localeCompare()` that allows whitespace characters to be collapsed or ignored. You can strip out whitespace from your strings before comparing.

Comment: @Pointy The reason why I was thiking it was due to the single quotes was because it was the only line where i experienced the issue. It was a bit misleading that when logging the text in the console it didnt show the breakline, it was only when i copied the text from the console into codepen that i noticed the breakline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing the issue with the breakline in the text by using a RegEx to remove breaklines before comparing the strings. The console was not displaying the breaklines when logging the text which was a bit misleading, and something to be aware of for the future.

```
let sanitizedTextItem = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '');
```